# Tokenizing a string into a list of nested arrays with Python

Tags: python, recursion, brainfuck

Following [this document](http://norvig.com/lispy.html) I'm writing an interpreter for [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), which in my implementation entails turning a string such as:

```
',>,<[>[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<<<-]>>.'
```

into a list of instructions like this:

```
[',', '>', ',', '<', [ '>', [ '-', '>', '+', '>', '+', '<', '<', ], '>', '>', [ '-', '<', '<', '+', '>', '>', ] '<', '<', '<', '-' ], '>', '>', '.']
```

or, minus the symbols:

```
[ ... [...] ... [...] ... ]
```

Right now I am solving this recursively using a deque and popleft() to iterate through the string one symbol at a time, but I feel like I should be breaking it into sub-arrays all at once.

How would you solve this problem in a Pythonic way?

(Ruling out Regex for speed reasons)

Comment: so you want a list of lists with the instructions separated?

Comment: I believe that you'll have to write a parser, you can write it in a "pythonic way" but I don't see any way around it. :)

Comment: have a look at the ast module and how it parses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it isn't exactly a "Pythonic way", but .... I find a solution to the problem using recursion and generators

```
s = ',>,<[>[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<<<-]>>.'

def brainfuck2list(brainfuck):
  while brainfuck:               #if list is empty then finish
    e = brainfuck.pop(0)
    if e not in ("[","]"):
      yield e
    elif e == "[":
      yield list(brainfuck2list(brainfuck))
    else:
      break

[_ for _ in brainfuck2list(list(s))]
```

you get following output

```
[
  ',', '>', ',', '<', 
  [
    '>', 
    [
      '-', '>', '+', '>', '+', '<', '<'
    ]
    , '>', '>', 
    [
      '-','<', '<', '+', '>', '>'
    ], 
    '<', '<', '<', '-'
  ]
  , '>', '>', '.'
]
```

Comment: I really like this approach, generator is definitely the right way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

For the curious, here is my working solution using recursion:

```
def tokenize(code):
  instructions = deque()

  if len(code) > 0:
    while len(code) > 0:
      if code[0] is "[":
        code.popleft()

        group = deque()
        r = 0

        while r > -1 and len(code) > 0:
          if code[0] is '[':
            group.append(code.popleft())
            r += 1

          elif code[0] is ']':
            if r is 0: 
              code.popleft()

            else:
              group.append(code.popleft())

            r -= 1

          else:
            group.append(code.popleft())

        instructions.append(tokenize(group))

      else:
        instructions.append(code.popleft())

    return instructions

else:
  return instructions
```

Answer (score 0):

I am almost there:

```
s=',>,<[>[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<<<-]>>.'

x = eval('["' + s.replace('[','",["').replace(']','"],"') + '"]')
```

This produces:

```
[',>,<', ['>', ['->+>+<<'], '>>', ['-<<+>>'], '<<<-'], '>>.']
```

Which is not exactly what you wanted, but you can iterate over the strings just as well.

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) if you are worried about security of eval.

**Update:** With regex, I made it all the way:

```
import re
s=',>,<[>[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]<<<-]>>.'
everything = re.compile("([^\]\[])")
y = eval('[' + everything.sub(r'"\1",',s).replace(",]","]").replace(']"','],"') + ']')
```

This becomes:

```
[',', '>', ',', '<', ['>', ['-', '>', '+', '>', '+', '<', '<'], '>', '>', ['-', '<', '<', '+', '>', '>'], '<', '<', '<', '-'], '>', '>', '.']
```

Comment: I hadn't considered using eval(), actually. Dangerous but it works.

Comment: If you need it to be safe, use `ast.literal_eval` instead

Comment: The OP does not want a regex solution

Comment: I've seen that, but I doubt their reasoning holds for an expression that does not need to backtrack. The first solution should work regardless.

Comment: Which  first solution?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the `eval` one.

Comment: Avoided a regex solution specifically for speed reasons, neither is really a great answer though. Running the regex solution vs. a working ugly solution using timeit gives a 'best speed' result of 100x slower. Both are interesting and clever, but not really what I was after.

Also worth noting the first solution causes empty elements when two brackets are next to each other ( [ '', [], ''] ) that would need to be checked for and removed at every level.